# ngx-graph often doesn't load in Angular page

Tags: angular, ngx-graph

I'm using ngx-graph for an org tree chart in an Angular 10 site and the chart often doesn't appear when the page loads (and it never loads in Cypress.io tests). There isn't any error, it just doesn't appear (big blank space) and I have to refresh once or twice to get it to show. The rest of the page loads without issue. Any advice on how to debug this?

I was able to repro the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-10-org-chart

I used this example as the starting point: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/demos/examples#organization-tree

Start of the template:

```
<ngx-graph
      [view]="[800, 500]"
      [links]="links"
      [nodes]="nodes"
      [curve]="curve"
      [layout]="layout"
      [nodeWidth]="150"
      [nodeHeight]="100"
      [layoutSettings]="layoutSettings"
      [enableZoom]="false"
      [autoZoom]="true"
      [draggingEnabled]="false"
    >
      <ng-template #defsTemplate>
        <svg:marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="8" refY="0" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" orient="auto">
          <svg:path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5" class="arrow-head" />
        </svg:marker>
      </ng-template>
```

Version:

"@swimlane/ngx-graph": "^7.2.0",

Edit:  [update$]="update$" doesn’t appear to do anything.  (As per [Reload ngx-graph with new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516376/reload-ngx-graph-with-new-data/54516721#54516721)). Also, I tried calling ngOnit() after changes and that doesn’t help either.

Comment: Are you updating the graph after the data has been initialized?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516376/reload-ngx-graph-with-new-data/54516721#54516721).

Comment: Yes,I tried that. It doesn’t seem to do anything. Thx for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Arcteezy I started with this example: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/demos/examples#organization-tree

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Comment: @Arcteezy yes thx. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-10-org-chart

Comment: There are errors in the demo.